# Do I need one certificate per client in gRPC?

Tags: .net, ssl, grpc, kestrel-http-server

I'm building an internal service across a corporate network using gRPC and I must ensure that the data is encrypted. For now, I have set a kestrel endpoint with a pfx certificate:

```
"HttpsInlineCertFile": {
    "Url": "https://localhost:9790",
    "Protocols": "Http2",
    "Certificate": {
      "Path": "Certificate.pfx",
      "Password": "<pass>"
    }
  }
```

On the client side I don´t use any certificates yet, I have created a single channel:

```
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:9790", new GrpcChannelOptions
        {
            HttpHandler = new WinHttpHandler()
        });
```

This works in localhost, but when I try to connect to the service from an external device it will throw an exception. I have some doubts about the implementation so far:

1. How does the client connect to the service using TLS if I haven't used any certificates? (Is it using a default certificate?)
2. Is it possible to create a infrastructure in which the server is the only one that holds a certificate?
3. Do I need a certificate for every client or is there any alternative to encrypt the data?
4. Is it safe to save the certificate password in the kestrel configuration file `"Password": "<pass>"`?

Comment: Depends whether you need to authenticate the client or not, and if so will you use certificates to do it. TLS does not itself depend on certificates, it's just that by convention a server needs to authenticate using one, and sometimes the client needs to also. If you want that then the easiest way on a corporate network is to use Group Policy to automatically issue certs to the machine or user, then configure your `Handler` to get the client certificate automatically from the store. If you don't do that then either you need another client authentication method (password?) or don't authenticate

Comment: @Charlieface, the authentication is done with a token-based system, I only need to encrypt the info. Can you extend more on the Group Policy solution? Is there any documentation I can read? Thanks.

Comment: If you already have your own authentication for the client then cleint certificates are not necessary. You just need the client to trust the issuer of the server's certificate. If you really want to issue client certificates, see http://woshub.com/how-to-deploy-certificate-by-using-group-policy/. You need your own private PKI setup with a CA server, which is not such a light undertaking and has security implications (you need to make sure you secure it otherwise it opens you to many risks). Speak to your IT admins, you may have that already. Honestly it's usually more bother than it's worth.